# Extend a nested list after checking if inner key exists SOS

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, extend

I am trying to build a nested dict with 2 levels of nesting. I am facing a problem while checking if inner key exists before updating the inner dict.

```
if ID not in dict:
    dict.update({key1:{key3['ID']:[item['VALUE']] }})
else:
    dict[key1][ID].extend([item['VALUE']])
```

the else part doesnt work as expected.

Comment: dict[key1][key3] will return a dictionary.
You were trying to append a dictionary which is invalid.
Try "dict[key1][key3]["ID"].append([item['VALUE']])"

Comment: @wei Sorry but I changed the question. I wrote incorrectly. I apologize

Comment: Still need to specify key3 `dict[key1][key3]['ID'].extend([item['VALUE']])`

Comment: I noticed that you were using ID as dictionary key instead of 'ID'

Comment: @wei thanks I tried with ```this dict[key1][key3]['ID'].extend([item['VALUE']])``` but my dict is still only of size one, as in the inner value is getting overwritten, means the extend part is not working. Could it be because of nested dict?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you need to specify '' during the creation and extraction of values from dictionaries in python i.e.

```
dict = { 'ID': 'yourid' }
print(dict['ID'])
```

Other than that if dict contains 'key1' as key and not 'ID' should the if condition not be

```
if ID not in dict['key1']:
```

Can you please provide more information on the structure of dict